# PrestaShop 1.7.5 - module kbmarketplace : override tpl doesn't work

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

ENGLISH

Hi everyone,
I have a problem with the modification of 2 TPL of the kbmarketplace module.
The site is in the initial phase of development and for now, it is only on my PC, so I can not provide FTP access as requested by the developers to help me.

Both files can be found in the dir / modules / kbmarketplace / views / templates / front / seller and copied them to my theme, so in
/ themes /child_food_restaurant/ modules /kbmarketplace /views/templates /front/seller
At each level, I also copied the index.php files
But loading the pages are shown the original files and not those that I have modified.

I have emptied and disabled the cache.

Can someone help me?

ITALIANO
Ciao a tutti,
ho un problema con la modifica di un paio di tpl del modulo kbmarketplace.
Il sito è in fase iniziale di sviluppo e per ora è solo sul mio pc, quindi non posso fornire un accesso FTP come richiesto dagli sviluppatori per aiutarmi.

Emtrambi i file si trovano nella dir /modules/kbmarketplace/views/templates/front/seller e li ho copiati nel mio tema, quindi in 
/themes/child_food_restaurant/modules/kbmarketplace/views/templates/front/seller 
Ad ogni livello ho copiato anche i file index.php
Però caricando le pagine interessate vengono mostrati i file originali e non quelli che ho modificato.

Ho svuotato e disabilitato la cache.

Qualcuno può aiutarmi?

Comment: Please share the php code, that how you call the tpl files ?

Comment: Hi Abdulla,
sorry for my bad English.
The problem is that the developer of the module has not managed possible overrides of the tpl in the /views/templates/front/seller directory.
I then had to modify a module controller: /controllers/front/KbFrontCore.php
Now I would like to be able to override the class in this file, to avoid risks due to updates.
The class in the KbFrontCore.php file is
class KbmarketplaceFrontCoreModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController {}

Comment: In the directory /override/modules/kbmarketplace/controllers/front I created the file KbmarketplaceFrontCoreModuleFrontController.php with the class 
class KbmarketplaceFrontCoreModuleFrontControllerOverride extends KbmarketplaceFrontCoreModuleFrontController
{}
but it is ignored: could you help me?
Thank you for your time

Comment: @AbdullaChozhimadathil, I didn't tag you in the previous comments

Comment: share the code please